# Sorting data by combine every 3 lines into one line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to sort some data in which every 3 lines are combined into one line by using Notepad++.

In short.

**The sorted data:**

[image]

```
VK_HANGUL   (0x15)    : IME Hangul mode
-           (0x16)    : Undefined
VK_JUNJA    (0x17)    : IME Junja mode
VK_FINAL    (0x18)    : IME final mode
VK_HANJA    (0x19)    : IME Hanja mode
VK_KANJI    (0x19)    : IME Kanji mode
-           (0x1A)    : Undefined
VK_ESCAPE   (0x1B)    : ESC key
```

**Unsorted data:**

[image]

```
VK_CONVERT
(0x1C)
: IME convert

VK_NONCONVERT
(0x1D)
: IME nonconvert

VK_ACCEPT
(0x1E)
: IME accept

VK_MODECHANGE
(0x1F)
: IME mode change request

VK_F3
(0x72)
: F3 key

VK_F4
(0x73)
: F4 key

VK_F5
(0x74)
: F5 key

VK_F6
(0x75)
: F6 key

VK_F7
(0x76)
: F7 key

VK_F8
(0x77)
: F8 key

VK_F9
(0x78)
: F9 key

VK_F10
(0x79)
: F10 key

VK_F11
(0x7A)
: F11 key

VK_F12
(0x7B)
: F12 key

VK_F13
(0x7C)
: F13 key

(0x51)
: Q key
```

**The following is what I want:**

[image]

Is it possible to do that by the regular expression?

Comment: Please use text not images.  Answerers do not want to retype your text to try it out.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I have updated the question to include the data.

Comment: A regular expression could work, but it would be difficult to make the columns line up.  Using tabs would help.  I'd probably just record a macro to convert 3 lines to one, and replay it for the whole file.

Comment: You could also do a replace of `\r\n` with `\t` on the whole file, then a replace of `\t\t` with `\r\n`.  Strip any trailing whitespace first if it exists.

Comment: Couldn't you look for `\R+(?=[:(])` and replace with nothing? [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/1B3aHs/1)

Comment: @revo: almost a correct regex and it does the desired, however, The last two lines are not sorted.

Comment: Then search for this `(.)\R(?=[:(])` and replace with `\1`. [**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/V04jOh/1)

Comment: @revo: The regex now works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
([^\r\n]+)\r\n([^\r\n]+)(?:\r\n([^\r\n]+)\r\n)?
```

and replace by this:

```
\1\t\2\t\3\r\n
```

that will merge three lines into one and separate them by tab (\t)

Comment: Your regex is near to the correct, but in some cases does not match something like that unsorted data `(0x51)
                : Q key`.

Comment: could you plz give a bit more elaborated example where it is not working ?

Comment: @LionKing the link doesn't work but is it the end of line that is causing problem ? i have updated the solution a bit... you may give it a try'

Comment: Almost everything is correct, but few have not been sorted but no matter.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities are a solution may not look for a 3-line merging process in order to output expected result. Looking at subject string you can search for:

```
(.)\R(?=[:(])
```

and replace it with:

```
\1 
  ^ space character here
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/V04jOh/1)